# Retrieving PDF files shown in WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

I'm using a `WebBrowser` control to perform a series of operations that result in showing a PDF document. When it comes to this point, the PDF is shown in an Adobe Reader Plugin hosted in `WebBrowser`, so I can't retrieve its content by handling the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event. I'm aware of this limitation. What I'd like to know is whether I can easily locate the temporary PDF file which is being displayed so I could retrieve it from its disk location. Does anyone know which directories I should query for it?